# Can't find UdpBasicApp.h file, fatal error: 'UdpBasicApp.h' file not found in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to extend UdpBasicApp, to implement my own UdpApp,when I compile I get this error : "./App.h:11:10: fatal error: 'UdpBasicApp.h' file not found". Here is my code :

```
#include <UdpBasicApp.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace omnetpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace inet;


class  App : public UdpBasicApp
{
     protected:
         virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
         virtual void handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) override;

     public:
         App() {}
         ~App();

};

Define_Module(App);
```

I also tried with the complete path : "inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h" but didn't work too.

Comment: Have you marked INET as reference project for your project?

Comment: Yes I did @JerzyD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"
```

Use quotes, not angled brakets.

Comment: yes, when I add the line :
#include "inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"

The UdpBasicApp word in :
class  App : public UdpBasicApp is recognized and become blue but when I Build the project I got an error.

Comment: The IDE should add all referenced projects to the include path automatically. As long as you marked INET as referenced project and rebuilt the Makefile, you should be fine. If nothing helps, you should check the output of the build process. INET prints the compiler flags at the beginning of the build process. Check the -I flags whether the command line contains a -I with the src folder of the INET project. That must be present otherwise the build will not work.